# How to intercept value binding by ng-model directive

Tags: angularjs

For example,

If I have a scope value:

```
$scope.bankInfo = '808,CityBank';
```

And an input field:

```
<input name="bank_number" ng-model="bankInfo " />
```

I don't know what is the proper way to bind my input field only to digit part (that is 808).
Should I use custom directive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that custom directive is a good approach to intercept binding.
Let declare a directive like this:

```
module.directive('banknumber', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, modelCtrl) {
                modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (inputValue) {
                    var modelValue = modelCtrl.$modelValue;
                    var bkno = (modelValue == null) ? '' : modelValue.split(',')[0];

                    return bkno;
                });

                modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                    var modelValue = modelCtrl.$modelValue;
                    var bankName = (modelValue == null) ? '' : modelValue.split(',')[1];

                    return modelCtrl.$viewValue + ',' + bankName;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

apply to input and it's done:

```
<input name="bank_number" ng-model="bankInfo" banknumber/>
```