# AngularJS: Can't ignore change event on an input field after user cancels with confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that shows a confirmation message to a user whenever a value is changed on an input field (radio, in this case).

So if "normal" is selected, the user clicks "tracked" and then cancels the confirmation box, I want both my model and view to be set back to "normal".

My input looks like this:

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type="radio" id="blah" name="blah" ng-model="emailType" value="normal" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure you want to do that?">
  <input type="radio" id="blah2" name="blah2" ng-model="emailType" value="tracked" ng-confirm-click="Really?">
</form>
```

Using ng-change really doesn't work for me, because if I say no in my confirmation, it will be too late: the value will already be changed.

I was trying to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969740/how-to-intercept-value-binding-by-ng-model-directive). My directive looks like this right now:

My directive looks like this:

```
app.register.directive('ngConfirmClick', [ function () {

    return {
         priority: -1,
         restrict: 'A',
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
                   var message = attrs.ngConfirmClick;

    modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                    var modelValue = modelCtrl.$modelValue;

                    if (inputValue !== modelValue && message && !confirm(message)) {
                        modelCtrl.$viewValue = modelValue;
                        modelCtrl.$render();
                    }

                    return modelCtrl.$viewValue;
                });
          }
    }
}]);
```

});

The parser triggers before the model change, I can confirm/cancel my confirmation box and I can change the value. But when the function returns, my model ends up being updated anyway with the new value.

I also tried $rollbackViewValue() according to one example I saw online, but it doesn't work (function not defined).

I'm sure I'm missing some really important step. Anyone can give a hand?

Comment: Do you NEED to cancel it before it changes or is changing it back if the user says no okay to do?

Comment: I don't want to cancel and clear selection. What I want is to go back to the previous value. So, in reality, I have 3 radio buttons, all binding to emailType. If the value is "normal" and I select "tracked" (another option), if the user says no, I want to go back to "normal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found your problem.

Change `modelCtrl.$viewValue = modelValue;` to `modelCtrl.$setViewValue(modelValue);`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cVh3/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. Unfortunately, it only clears selection. I wanted to go back to previous option. I'll make it clearer in my initial post and play a little bit more with it today.

Comment: Actually, it does work. The problem was some garbage code I still had from the initial example I used. setViewValue calls back all the parsers with the old value and I was returning not the old value, but the old value concatenated with another other string. Of course it wouldn't match. Now it works, thanks!